# Update if post with specific title exists

Tags: php, posts, customization

I am trying to create a post, if it does not exist and update the post by its title if it exists. The title is unique, because its the users username.

However, the update functionality does not work. A new post gets created all the time.

The following code creates and *should* update the post:

```
<td><input type="submit" class="button button-primary" name="info_update_config" value="Save Changes" /></td>    


    <?php

function wp_exist_post_by_title($title)
{
    global $wpdb;
    $return = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT ID FROM wp_posts WHERE post_title = '" . $title . "' && post_status = 'publish' && post_type = 'post' ", 'ARRAY_N');
    if (empty($return)) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}

if (isset($_POST['info_update_config'])) {

    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    $user_id      = get_current_user_id();

    // usage
    if (wp_exist_post_by_title($current_user->user_login)) {

        $id = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT ID FROM wp_posts WHERE post_title = '" . $title . "' && post_status = 'publish' && post_type = 'post' ", 'ARRAY_N');

        $my_post = array(
            'ID' => $id,
            'post_title' => $current_user->user_login,
            'post_content' => $current_user->user_email
        );

        // Update the post into the database
        wp_update_post($my_post);

        // save a basic text value
        $field_key = "field_577431181309c";
        $value     = $uids;
        update_field($field_key, $value, $my_post);

    } else {

        $my_post = array(
            'post_title' => $current_user->user_login,
            'post_content' => $current_user->user_email,
            'post_status' => 'draft',
            'post_author' => $user_id
        );

        // Insert the post into the database
        $postID = wp_insert_post($my_post);

        // save a basic text value
        $field_key = "field_577431181309c";
        $value     = $uids;
        update_field($field_key, $value, $postID);
    }
}
//}

?>
```

Any suggestions what I am doing wrong?

Kind regards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I would use `WP_Query` instead of the manual DB query (and don't tell me that's because of performance because you're querying 2 times the same thing). Second, you're saving your post as `draft` status and querying post with status `publish`

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Could you please provide a working example?  (which is more performant than mine)